# Let $A,B$ and $U$ be sets so that $A\subseteq U$ and $B \subseteq U$. Prove that $A \subseteq B$ iff $(U\setminus B) \subseteq (U\setminus A).$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let $A,B$ and $U$ be sets so that $A\subseteq U$ and $B \subseteq U$. Prove that $A \subseteq B$ iff $(U\setminus B) \subseteq (U\setminus A).$

I've this question as my graded assignment. But for the entire module, I am completely lost and would really appreciate if anybody can help me with this question. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Every member of $A$ is a member of $B$.

Equivalently, everything that is **not** a member of $B$ is **not** a member of $A$.

"If $P$ then $Q$" is equivalent to "If not $Q$ then not $P$".

You can see that be making a truth table:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline P & Q & \text{If } P \text{ then } Q. & \text{If not } Q \text{ then not } P. \\
\hline
T & T & T & T \\
T & f & f & f \\
f & T & T & T \\
f & f & T & T \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
Let $P$ be the statement $x\in A$ and let $Q$ be $x\in B$.  Then we have
$$
\forall x\in U\  \Big( \text{if } P \text{ then } Q \Big).
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
\forall x\in U\  \Big( \text{if not } Q \text{ then not } P \Big).
$$